# regexp: Name starts from prefix

Tags: regex

I'd like to create a regular expression, but unfortunately my idea didn't work The regular expression should only permit the entry of a string consisting of two parts:

Part one: prefix `_test_`

Part two: letters (a-z), digits (0-9) characters: dot.

Valid examples:

- `_test_adm1234`
- `_test_abcd_xyz`
- `_test_xyz_123`
- `_test_123_xyz`

No matching examples:

- `test_123`
- `_Test_123_abc`
- `_123_test_`
- `_TEST_1234`
- `_test_123-abc`

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: What regex engine/programming language are you using, and what did you try that didn't work? (And why do some of your "valid" examples have an underscore in part two when your specification doesn't mention that's valid?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following, I am unclear because your second part contains an *underscore* (`_`) as well in your **valid** examples, but you did not specify that it was supposed to be considered a matching character.

```
^_test_[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*$
```

See [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/sN2zG6)